# Row value multiplication not working in android sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I want to multiply quantity to item_price on each row and store it on the total on each row. Here's the code I have written in my DatabaseHelper class: (TICKET_TABLE is the variable where the table name is stored)

```
 public Cursor getTicketTotal(){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data=db.rawQuery("SELECT quantity,item_price, quantity*item_price as  "+"total from "+TICKET_TABLE,null);
        return data;
    }
```

and this is how I am calling it from an activity. But,it's not working. My `quantity` is an integer field and `item_price` is a REAL. What' the issue here?

```
DatabaseHelper myDb;
myDb.getTicketTotal();
```

Here's the screenshot of the database:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: The 'total' value remains 0 on each column. I checked the query and it worked fine. But I don't know why the value isn't adding to the total. Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: Do you know what's the way to run the getTicketTotal() function properly from my activity?

Comment: Your query looks OK. This might be a problem with the data. Does something simple like `SELECT quantity+1, ...` work?

Comment: I ran the query separately on DB sqlite browser and it worked perfect. Even my code not showing any error but still I guess I have issues with my activity code from where I am calling the function.

Answer (score -2):

You are just using select query to view the formatted output.

If you want to persist total value in Column in database then you have to use update query to multiply the item_price  and quantity.

update TICKET_TABLE set total=quantity*item_price ;

Comment: So you are telling that I am not supposed to run SELECT ?

Comment: But, I have already ran my query on database separately and it worked fine.

Comment: It depends on your requirement.If you want to store totalin database then use update query else use select query to get total at runtime

Comment: What I am saying is there seems no issue with my query.

Comment: So what's the answer then?

Comment: It seems you didn't get what my question is.

Comment: You are running dynamic total on runtime ,So in database if you manually view it will always show 0 . But runtime it will show actual total by multiplying in query. If any issue  loop cursor and show the logcat output by print column values

Comment: You are running dynamic total on runtime??? I didn't get that.. Please explain to me.